# MacOS- Can't open a NSWindow in command line app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I use Xcode to create an command line app for MacOS.And I want to open a NSWindow,However,the nswindow failed to display.Is this possible?

Here's the demo code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    NSUInteger styleMask = NSWindowStyleMaskTitled|NSWindowStyleMaskClosable|NSWindowStyleMaskResizable|NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable;
    NSRect rect = [NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame styleMask:styleMask];
    NSWindow *nswindow =  [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:styleMask backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:false];
    [nswindow center];
    [nswindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [nswindow orderFrontRegardless];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You create the window and then you exit the app immediately. You need a runloop.

Comment: Add [NSApp run] at the end and it should work.